# How to add unprocessed strings to a DataFrame in python?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a string `object` that is looking like this:

```
Numărul de camere
3 camere
Suprafaţa totală
77 m²
Suprafaţa bucătăriei
11 m²
Tipul clădirii
Dat în exploatare
Etaj
3
Locul de amplasare în casă
In mijlocul casei
Grup sanitar
separat
Balcon/lojă
2
Parcare
acoperită
Încălzire autonomă
✔
```

This is data parsed from a web site. I want to add the data to a `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID','Numarul de camere','Suprafata totala',
                       'Suprafata bucatariei','Tipul cladirii','Etaj',
                      'Amplasarea in bloc', 'Grup sanitar', 'Balcon/loja',
                      'Parcare', 'Incalzire autonoma'])
```

Each second row of strings is a characteristic and I want to add it to his place in my `DataFrame`. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text = """Numărul de camere
3 camere
Suprafaţa totală
77 m²
Suprafaţa bucătăriei
11 m²
Tipul clădirii
Dat în exploatare
Etaj
3
Locul de amplasare în casă
In mijlocul casei
Grup sanitar
separat
Balcon/lojă
2
Parcare
acoperită
Încălzire autonomă
✔ """

#split the string
s = text.split('\n')

import pandas as pd

d = {k:v for k, v in zip(s[0::2],s[1::2])}
df = pd.DataFrame([d])

print df.head()

# if you want to preserve the order of the columns
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('Values', s[1::2])], orient='index',columns=s[0::2])

print df.head()
```

Comment: this is smart !

Comment: @juluribk In the case that there are one missing key how to set the values for that key as NaN? for instance :
 `Numărul de camere
Suprafaţa totală
77 m²`  I want to replace the missing value `3 camere` with NaN

Comment: import numpy as np
df['Numărul de camere'] = np.NaN